# I can not play animation on AI, unity 2d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a firefly for my game, which is an AI.I wanted it to make across the map, for that I watched a tutorial on YT from BlackThornProd, but when I tried animating it, and played the game, it was terrible, the animation were playing bizarre, like when the firefly needs to go on the right, the animations are playing like this; Left-Right-Idle-Right-etc.Im using Blend Tree.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NPCRandomMoveing : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform[] moveSpots;
    private int randomSpot;
    private float waitTime;
    public float startWaitTime;
    public Animator anim;
    Vector2 movement;

    void Start()
    {
        waitTime = startWaitTime;
        randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots[randomSpot].position) < 0.2f){
            if(waitTime <= 0){
                randomSpot = Random.Range(0, moveSpots.Length);
                waitTime = startWaitTime;
            } else {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", transform.position.x);
        anim.SetFloat("Vertical", transform.position.y);
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", transform.position.sqrMagnitude);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your Animator Controller? The problem lies there 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I think you move your fly and also try to animate its position right? Try maybe to just animate and dont change the transforms or even better rotate your fly with lookat vector and use animation controler to just adjust the speed of wings.

Try this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateTowardsSpline : MonoBehaviour
{
    // put the points from unity interface
    public List<Transform> wayPointList = new List<Transform>();

    public int currentWayPoint = 0;
    Transform targetWayPoint;

    public float speed = 0f;
    public float turningRate = 1f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (currentWayPoint < this.wayPointList.Count - 1)
        {
            if (targetWayPoint == null)
                targetWayPoint = wayPointList[currentWayPoint];// hier put a random nr
            RotateTowards();
        }
    }

    void RotateTowards()
    {
        // rotate towards the target
        transform.forward = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.right, targetWayPoint.position - transform.position, 0.02f * (speed) * Time.deltaTime, 1.0f);

    }
}
```

Comment: Im sorry to say, but this script don't work, like when I press play, the firefly glitches and plays all the animations, and it stays on the same position, not moving at all

Comment: First remove the animations and focus on movement. This script i used for Train like movement meaning if follows the Waypoints one after another. You will need to change the targetWaypoint to random nr between your position elements array length. Since you have a 2D game probably use vector2 and transform.right might not be appropriate

Comment: and change the speed and turning values i forgot